# XSL 1.0 - Adding new invoice lines

Tags: xslt

Take this xml structure as a starting point:

```
<records>
  <E1EDP01>
    <POSEX>00001</POSEX>
    <BRGEW>302.176</BRGEW>
    <NTGEW>243.257</NTGEW>
    <E1EDP19>
      <QUALF>007</QUALF>
      <IDTNR>2105009900</IDTNR>
    </E1EDP19>
    <E1EDP26 SEGMENT="1">
      <QUALF>003</QUALF>
      <BETRG>965.58</BETRG>
    </E1EDP26>
  </E1EDP01>
  <E1EDP01>
    <POSEX>00002</POSEX>
    <BRGEW>134.520</BRGEW>
    <NTGEW>122.835</NTGEW>
    <E1EDP19>
      <QUALF>007</QUALF>
      <IDTNR>2105009900</IDTNR>
    </E1EDP19>
    <E1EDP26 SEGMENT="1">
      <QUALF>003</QUALF>
      <BETRG>1630.20</BETRG>
    </E1EDP26>
  </E1EDP01>
  <E1EDP01>
    <POSEX>00003</POSEX>
    <BRGEW>5.000</BRGEW>
    <NTGEW>4.000</NTGEW>
    <E1EDP19>
      <QUALF>007</QUALF>
      <IDTNR>2105001000</IDTNR>
    </E1EDP19>
    <E1EDP26 SEGMENT="1">
      <QUALF>003</QUALF>
      <BETRG>1773.78</BETRG>
    </E1EDP26>
  </E1EDP01>
</records>
```

Basically this is an invoice with 3 lines and 2 distinct products (because of E1EDP19/IDTNR field).

The results needs to look something like this:

```
<xml>
  <line>
    <rowid>1</rowid>
    ... stuff not really relevant ...
  </line>
  <line>
    <rowid>2</rowid>
    ... stuff not really relevant ...
  </line>
  <line>
    <rowid>3</rowid>
    ... stuff not really relevant ...
  </line>
  <line>
    <rowid>4</rowid>
    <doucdtot>1</doucdtot>
    <doucd>2105009900<doucd>
    <waarde>2.595,78</waarde>
    <brutto>436,70</brutto>
    <netto>366,09</netto>
  </line>
  <line>
    <rowid>5</rowid>
    <doucdtot>1</doucdtot>
    <doucd>2105001000<doucd>
    <waarde>1.773,78</waarde>
    <brutto>5,00</brutto>
    <netto>4,00</netto>
  </line>
</xml>
```

In other words, I need to extract from the original xml the non-duplicate E1EDP19/IDTNR (these will be my DOUCD values), and for the 2 non-duplicate values, I need to:

- sum up E1EDP01/E1EDP26/BETRG and this will be my WAARDE field value
- sum up E1EDP01/BRGEW and this will be my BRUTTO field value
- sum up E1EDP01/NTGEW and this will be my NETTO field value
- make 2 new invoice lines, with incrementing ROWID (just like in the result described above - the 3 original invoice lines remain with their specific logic & formatting, and these 2 new lines must be added at the end).

Now, executing this particular piece of code on the original xml (above) ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:decimal-format name="d" decimal-separator="," grouping-separator="." />
<xsl:key name="key1" match="E1EDP01" use="E1EDP19[QUALF='007']/IDTNR"/>
<xsl:template match="records">
    <xml>
        <xsl:for-each select="E1EDP01[count(. | key('key1', E1EDP19[QUALF='007']/IDTNR)[1]) = 1]">
            <line>
                <ROWID></ROWID>
                <doucdtot>1</doucdtot>
                <DOUCD>
                    <xsl:value-of select="E1EDP19[QUALF='007']/IDTNR"/>
                </DOUCD>
                <WAARDE>
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(key('key1', E1EDP19[QUALF='007']/IDTNR)/E1EDP26[QUALF='003']/BETRG), '#.##0,00', 'd' )"></xsl:value-of>
                </WAARDE>
                <BRUTO>
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(key('key1', E1EDP19[QUALF='007']/IDTNR)/BRGEW), '#.##0,00', 'd' )"></xsl:value-of>
                </BRUTO>
                <NETTO>
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(key('key1', E1EDP19[QUALF='007']/IDTNR)/NTGEW), '#.##0,00', 'd' )"></xsl:value-of>
                </NETTO>
            </line>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xml>
</xsl:template>
```

... you will end up with most of the problem solved, *except* for the `<rowid>` part, which, for the life of me, can't figure out how on Earth I could do it ...

- I know I can find out how many "original lines" the invoice has (`<xsl:value-of select="count(E1EDP01/POSEX)"/>`)
- I know I can find out how many "new lines" I must add at the end (make a new key `<xsl:key name="key2" match="E1EDP19" use="IDTNR"/>` and make a variable be `<xsl:value-of select="count(/*/*/E1EDP19[generate-id() = generate-id(key('key2', IDTNR)[1])])"></xsl:value-of>`)
- How do I tie the two together???

Please help?

Thank you,
T.

PS: goes without saying that I'm fairly new at this, all the logic described here comes from this site (so massive thanks to the *other* guys who helped me without knowing ;))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
<ROWID><xsl:value-of select="count(../E1EDP01)+position()"/></ROWID>
```

Comment: Note that this will re-count the original number of rows for every additional line item. Probably not a big deal, but I'd recommend storing it in a variable that calculates the value only once.

Answer (score 0):

How's this (I included a bit of tidying):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:decimal-format name="d" decimal-separator="," grouping-separator="." />
  <xsl:key name="key1" match="E1EDP01" use="E1EDP19[QUALF='007']/IDTNR"/>

  <xsl:variable name="numFmt" select="'#.##0,00'" />
  <xsl:varialbe name="origLineCount" select="count(/records/E1EDP01)" />

  <xsl:template match="records">
    <xml>
      <xsl:apply-templates 
         select="E1EDP01[generate-id() = 
                         generate-id(key('key1', E1EDP19[QUALF='007']/IDTNR)[1])]" />
    </xml>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="E1EDP01">
    <xsl:variable name="id" select="E1EDP19[QUALF='007']/IDTNR"/>
    <xsl:variable name="mySet" select="key('key1', $id)" />

    <line>
      <ROWID>
        <xsl:value-of select="position() + $origLineCount"/>
      </ROWID>
      <doucdtot>1</doucdtot>
      <DOUCD>
        <xsl:value-of select="$id"/>
      </DOUCD>
      <WAARDE>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum($mySet/E1EDP26[QUALF='003']/BETRG),
                                            $numFmt, 'd' )" />
      </WAARDE>
      <BRUTO>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum($mySet/BRGEW), $numFmt, 'd' )" />
      </BRUTO>
      <NETTO>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum($mySet/NTGEW), $numFmt, 'd' )" />
      </NETTO>
    </line>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```